# ¿En que puede afectar usar dentro del contexto la extension asNoTracking()?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estoy realizando varios movimientos a la vez, y ocupo lograr que si en una pantalla hago una salida, en la otra estando abierta me compruebe la existencia de datos, por eso estoy utilizando la extension de Linq "asNoTracking" para poder asi consultar los datos correctos de la BD.

```
var all = this._contexto.CodigosArticulos.AsNoTracking();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consultas LINQ con NoTracking

El uso de NoTracking() es recomendado cuando tu consulta esta pensada solo para realizar operaciones de lectura, asi tu obtendras las entidades materializadas por Entity Framework pero estas no se les hara seguimiento(no seran **trackeadas**) por el contexto. Esto asegura el uso minimo de memoria y un mejor desempeño.

> #### Ventajas
>
> - Desempeño mejorado comparado con las consultas LINQ regulares.
>
> #### Desventajas
>
> - Debes cambiar manualmente el estado de la entidad debido a que el seguimiento de cambios esta desactivado.

**Ejemplo, si deseas actualizar una entidad obtenida de una consulta con NoTracking():**

```
//Deberas cambiar manualmente el estado de la entrada asociada a la entidad
ctx.Entry(CodigosArticulo).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Referencia

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#5

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, ya habia estado investigando, pero ahora me queda un poco mas claro todo esto.